# Overloading assignment operator without knowing the class structure

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose there's a class `Human` that has a list of pets. A pet can be a `Cat` or a `Dog`. In order to avoid object slicing, I declared the objects inside the list as pointers to base class `Pet`.

For now, when I want to make a copy of a human by calling `operator=`, I need to check for each pet whether it is a dog or a cat. With this approach if, for example, I add a new type of pet, let's call it `Fish`, I have to remember to add (inside `Human::operator=`) an if statement that checks if the pet is a fish.

My question is: Is it possible to implement the `operator=` (or the copy constructor) for the class Human without downcasting (without checking all the types a pet can be)?

```
class Pet {
    public:
    virtual std::string getType()=0;
};

class Cat : public Pet {
    public:
    std::string getType() {
        return "Cat";
    }
};

class Dog : public Pet {
    public:
    std::string getType() {
        return "Dog";
    }
};

class Human {
    public:
    void addPet(Pet* pet) {
        this->pets.push_back(pet);
    }

    virtual std::list<Pet*> getPets() const {
        return this->pets;
    }

    Human& operator=(const Human& other) {
        std::list<Pet*> pets=other.getPets();
        std::list<Pet*>::iterator i=pets.begin(), end=pets.end();
        for(;i!=end;i++) {
                if(dynamic_cast<Cat*>(*i)) {
                    this->pets.push_back(new Cat);
                } else if(dynamic_cast<Dog*>(*i)) {
                    this->pets.push_back(new Dog);
                }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    private:
    std::list<Pet*> pets;
};

int main()
{
   Human* joe=new Human;
   joe->addPet(new Cat);
   joe->addPet(new Dog);
   Human bob=*joe;
   delete joe;
   std::list<Pet*> pets=bob.getPets();
   std::list<Pet*>::iterator i=pets.begin(), end=pets.end();
   for(;i!=end;i++) {
    std::cout<<(*i)->getType()<<std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Nick what do you mean?

Comment: Do you need the pushed object to be a copy of `i` or just of the same type?

Comment: @Nick they should be a copy

Comment: In that case Matteo Italia's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally what you do is to implement correctly the copy constructor of each derived class (which in many cases means just leaving just the default one).

Then, you declare in your base class something like

```
virtual Base* clone()=0;
```

And in each derived class is implemented as:

```
virtual Base* clone() 
{
    return new Derived(*this);
}
```

Now, each time you want a copy of an object of your class hierarchy just call its `clone()` method. This avoids slicing since the version of clone that is called is the one of the actual type, so the correct copy constructor gets called.

Comment: Suppose, for example, that my derived classes have some members. In this case, should i call the operator= for each member before return the new object?

Comment: I believe this is what he suggests that you do: `this->pets.push_back((*i)->clone());`

Comment: does `return new Derived(*this);` call the `Derived` copy constructor right?

Comment: Exactly. That has to be done for every derived class (of course replacing `Derived` with the actual class name).

Answer (score 1):

Give `Pet` a virtual `clone()` method, and then call it when needed, eg:

```
class Pet
{
public:
    virtual ~Pet() {}
    virtual std::string getType()=0;
    virtual Pet* clone()=0;
};

class Cat : public Pet
{
public:
    std::string getType() {
        return "Cat";
    }
    virtual Pet* clone() {
        return new Cat(*this);
    }
};

class Dog : public Pet
{
public:
    std::string getType() {
        return "Dog";
    }
    virtual Pet* clone() {
        return new Dog(*this);
    }
};

class Human
{
public:
    void addPet(Pet* pet) {
        this->pets.push_back(pet);
    }

    virtual std::list<Pet*> getPets() const {
        return this->pets;
    }

    Human& operator=(const Human& other) {
        for (std::list<Pet*>::iterator i = this->pets.begin(), end = this->pets.end(); i != end; ++i) {
            delete *i;
        }
        this->pets.clear();
        std::list<Pet*> pets = other.getPets();
        for (std::list<Pet*>::iterator i = pets.begin(), end = pets.end(); i != end; ++i) {
            std::auto_ptr<Pet> pet((*i)->clone());
            this->pets.push_back(pet.get());
            pet.release();
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::list<Pet*> pets;
};

int main()
{
    Human* joe = new Human;
    joe->addPet(new Cat);
    joe->addPet(new Dog);
    Human bob = *joe;
    delete joe;
    std::list<Pet*> pets = bob.getPets();
    for (std::list<Pet*>::iterator i = pets.begin(), end = pets.end(); i != end; ++i) {
        std::cout << (*i)->getType() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what `std::auto_ptr<Pet> pet(i->clone());` does?

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is a smart wrapper. Its destructor calls `delete` on the pointer it is holding. I am using it as a safety catch to `delete` the cloned `Pet` if `push_back()` throws an exception and thus the clone is not added to the list. If you don't `delete` the clone when `push_back()` fails, that would be a memory leak.